# Canvas scroll in wpf when scaled transformed

Tags: wpf, canvas, zooming, scrollviewer

I have customized a canvas to support the zooming. I am doing this by scale transformation.
I have scroll viewer wrapped around canvas but scroll bars are not visible when canvas is zoomed.

I came to know that scale transformation does not changes the actual size of the UIElement that is why scroll bars are not visible when canvas is zoomed.

Is there any alternate solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can increase the actual size instead by either binding the scroll bar to the size. Or you can use LayoutTransfrom instead: read [here](http://patconroy.wordpress.com/2009/03/24/layouttransform-vs-rendertransform-in-wpf/) about the difference between it and RenderTransform.

Comment: Thanks! I have used LayoutTransfrom.